# why would sendgrid marketing section be unauthorized

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I just set up a SendGrid account via Azure portal.
When I go to the management page I can select Marketing Campaigns but i get unauthorized toast messages. I can't access any of the settings, nor any of the subsections.

Are there limits to the Azure version?

Are there limits to the Free version?

I'm using the free account

Comment: I am getting same error too when I create SendGrid account from azure.

Answer (score 1):

From https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/partners/microsoft-azure/:

"Customers that integrate through the Azure Marketplace, do not have access to SendGrid's Marketing Campaigns."

I don't know the reasoning behind this restriction but it is certainly inconvenient.